# DOORS make console the interactive window

Tags: cmd, ibm-doors

Is there any way to tell DOORS to use the current command prompt window as the interactive window when executing in batch mode?

For example, if I have `hello.dxl` which looks like

```
print("Hello world")
```

and `Run.bat` which looks like

```
"C:\Program Files\IBM\Rational\DOORS\9.6\bin\doors.exe" -u test -pass testPass -b hello.dxl -W
```

It currently opens a new window, prints "Hello World" and then closes the window (it closes it because of the `-W`). Is there any way to redirect this output to the command prompt window that was opened to run the batch file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no console variant of doors.exe and as far as I know there is no possibility to give a sort of handle to a specific prompt window and use e.g. OLE Automation to print to this window, so, basically, no, it's not possible.

A workaround that we use for this requirement is to have a batch file which

1. generates the name to a temporary file ,
2. passes this file to DOORS as a parameter (using environment variables)
3. make DOORS/DXL `cout` to this file
4. after the DXL has finished, `type` the content of the temporary file in the calling batch and optionally delete it.

PS: according to https://www.ibm.com/mysupport/s/question/0D50z00006HIM4oCAH/doors-print-redirect-tutorial-for-print-cout-and-logfiles it apparently used to be possible to redirect STDOUT/STDERR to a specific file, but not in recent DOORS versions.

Comment: Thanks for this. Just playing around, I found in my DXL I can just do `cout << "Hi"` and in my batch I can just put `> Temp.txt` and it will output it to the file without needing to play around with environment variables

Comment: Thanks for the information, good to know. I had tried this, but it seems I did some mistake while playing around.